# 3 conditional views in render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to render a update form when clicking a record, a new record form when a date-picker is clicked, and neither after update/create. I have a prop that dynamically changes its values based on user input called `editMode`.

Here is a screenshot of what values `this.props.editMode` has from the console with different values, in addition to `this.props.events` to show it's not empty and even one object in the array has a matching id to the `recordId` found it `this.props.editMode`

[image]

[image]

`<Create />` component will renders, but the `<Update />` component will not. I'm only getting a warning in the console.

> Warning: Create is changing a controlled input of type text to be uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

No errors.

```
import React from 'react';


import Create from './Event/Create';
import Update from './Event/Update';

class SideBar extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.renderEventForm = this.renderEventForm.bind(this);
  }

  renderEventForm() {

    console.log(this.props.editMode);
    console.log(this.props.events);

    //if editMode state true, loop
    // through events till until matching id
    // place props into update component

    if(this.props.editMode.state) {
      const editRecordId = this.props.editMode.recordId;
      return this.props.events.map((e) => {
        if(e.Id === editRecordId) {
              <div key={e.Id}>
                <Update event={e} />
              </div>
        }
      });
    } else {
      // render the create form
     return(
       <Create/>
     )
   }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="slds-p-bottom--small slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--1-of-1 slds-large-size--1-of-3">
        {this.renderEventForm()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SideBar;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `map` for this kind of cases, `map` is used when you want to `return` something for each element, in your case you just want to iterate the array to check the correct element, instead of map use other iterator that you can break in the middle by using `return` or `break`. Use this:

```
if(this.props.editMode.state) {
    const editRecordId = this.props.editMode.recordId;
    let events = this.props.events;
    for(i in events){
        if(events[i].Id === editRecordId) {
            return <Update event={events[i]} />
        }
    };
}else{
    return(<Create/>)
}
```

With map if you do not return anything then it will return undefined by default. So in your case it will return something like this:

`[undefined, **some element** , undefined, undefined]`

Check this:

```js
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
b = a.map((e)=>{
         if(e % 2 == 0)
             return e;
    });
    
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything in your `.map` function. You should add return inside a map function. See below.

```
return this.props.events.map((e) => {
  if(e.Id === editRecordId) {
    return (<div key={e.Id}>
      <Update event={e} />
    </div>)
  }
}
```